# Why is closure property not working in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I am new to node js and taking a course to learn it. However, I am not able to make a simple closure property of javascript work in it. I have 2 files index.js and rectangle.js where in I am using callback to return the area & perimeter of rectangle.

**index.js**

```
var rect = require('./rectangle');

function solveRect(l,b) {
    console.log("Solving for rectangle with l = " + l + "and b = " + b);

    rect(l,b, (err,rectangle) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log("The area of rectangle of dimensions l = " 
                + l + "and b = " + b + " is "  + rectangle.area());

            console.log("The perimeter of rectangle of dimensions l = " 
                + l + "and b = " + b + " is "  + rectangle.perimeter());
        }
    });
    console.log("This statement is after the call to rect()");
}

solveRect(2,4);
solveRect(3,5);
solveRect(0,4);
solveRect(-3,-5);
```

**rectangle.js**

```
module.exports = (x,y,callback) => {
    if( x <= 0 || y <= 0) {
        setTimeout(() =>
            callback(new Error("rectangle dimensions should be greater than zero"),
                null),
            2000
        );
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(() =>
            callback(null,
                {
                    perimeter: (x,y) => (2*(x+y)),
                    area: (x,y) => (x*y)
                }),
            2000
        );
    }
}
```

I see that since length and breadth are already available to the callback from the outer scope, there isn't any need to pass them when we call the rectangle.area() function.

**Output:** I get NaN returned as area and perimeter and not the actual calculated area.

Answer (score 2):

The `perimiter` and `area` functions take arguments `x` and `y`, so they use those arguments to calculate the results, not the variables inherited from the closure. Since you're not supplying any arguments when you call them in `solveRect()`, you're performing arithmetic on `undefined`, which results in `NaN`.

Get rid of the arguments so they'll use the closure variables.

```
        setTimeout(() =>
            callback(null,
                {
                    perimeter: () => (2*(x+y)),
                    area: () => (x*y)
                }),
            2000
        );
```